# How to use a semicolon separator with csvsimple together with babel (french language)?

Tags: babel, csv, csvsimple, babel-french

### 1) Semicolon `;` separator and babel

Using the package `csvsimple`, I found that I can use a semicolon `;` separator *only if the `babel` package is not loaded*:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage[french]{babel} % Comment to avoid error
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{TestSemicolon.csv}
surname;name
MOUSE;Mickey
DUCK;Donald
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
  \csvreader[
    head to column names,
    separator=semicolon,
    ]{TestSemicolon.csv}{}{%
    \surname~\name\\
    }%
\end{document}
```

I get the following error since `\surname` and `\name` appear not to be defined:

```
Undefined control sequence
```

### 2) Comma `,` separator and babel

Whereas, if I use a comma `,` separator (default option in `csvsimple`), everything seems to be working fine:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,margin=0.5cm]{standalone}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{filecontents*}{TestComma.csv}
surname,name
MOUSE,Mickey
DUCK,Donald
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
  \csvreader[
    head to column names,
    ]{TestComma.csv}{}{%
    \surname~\name\\
    }%
\end{document}
```

[image: Output with a comma separator and babel loaded]

Is it possible to use a semicolon `;` separator with `csvsimple` together with `babel`?

Comment: This only seems to be reproducible with `\usepackage[french]{babel}`. Using a different language option such as `english`, `spanish` or `ngerman` results in the desired output.

Comment: On my computer, I had tried with `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` but I was running into a different `Missing \endcsname inserted` error... Maybe I did something wrong.

I will change the question accordingly, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to disable the special meaning `;` has with `babel-french`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname-semicolon.csv}
surname;name
MOUSE;Mickey
DUCK;Donald
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\csvreader[
  before reading=\shorthandoff{;},
  head to column names,
  separator=semicolon,
]{\jobname-semicolon.csv}{}{%
    \surname~\name\\
}
and some other text.

\end{document}
```

Avoid `utf8x`, it has been unmaintained for several years.

[image]